# Можно ли редактировать текст с помощью Regex без цикла?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Например выполнить задачу с помощью Regex:

*Текст на ввод:* **it (cap) was the best of TIMES (low)**
*Текст на вывод:* **It was the best of times**

(cap) это у нас в роле Сapitalize,и суть задачи применить функцию на предыдущий элемент.

Я сделал задачу разделив вес текст через Split на отдельный элемент и поместиль на массив,и на каждый элемент применяль фукнцию через индекс пропустив через цикл весь массив.

**Вопрос:**  Можно ли через Regex проделать все это без цикла и массива?

мой код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]
    f := args[0]

    file, err := os.ReadFile(f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    split_sep := regexp.MustCompile(`\(.*?\)|\S*`)
    Formatted_text := split_sep.FindAllString(string(file), -1)

    for i := 0; i < len(Formatted_text); i++ {

        cap := regexp.MustCompile(`\(cap\)`)
        findCap := cap.MatchString(Formatted_text[i])

        if findCap {

            Formatted_text[i-1] = (strings.Title(Formatted_text[i-1]))

            Formatted_text[i] = ""

        }

        low := regexp.MustCompile(`\(low\)`)
        findLow := low.MatchString(Formatted_text[i])

        if findLow {

            Formatted_text[i-1] = (strings.ToLower(Formatted_text[i-1]))

            Formatted_text[i] = ""
        }
}
```

Comment: Так же как луше удалять из текста не нужный фрагмент.Вместо Formatted_text[i] = " ".Что бы лишний пробел не создавать

Answer (score 1):

Пример кода, которые решает проблему с использованием двух вызовов [`regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc`:](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc)

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    re_cap := regexp.MustCompile(`\S+\s+\(cap\)`)
    re_low := regexp.MustCompile(`\S+\s+\(low\)`)
    text := "it (cap) was the best of TIMES (low)"
    fmt.Println(
        re_cap.ReplaceAllStringFunc(
            re_low.ReplaceAllStringFunc(text, func(m string) string {
                return strings.ToLower(strings.Fields(m)[0])
            }), func(n string) string {
                return strings.Title(strings.Fields(n)[0])
            }))
}
```

Результат:

```
It was the best of times
```